# How to prevent player and computer winning at the same time, python game?

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been following a tutorial on a tic tac toe game that plays against the computer, the game works fine. However there is a possibility the player and computer can win at the same time. I'm assuming its because when the player clicks, the computer makes its move at the exact same time. I was wondering if time.sleep(x) would work after the player move and before the computer move. Im having trouble understanding where it would go.

```
hasClicked = True
clickCount = 0

buttonGrid = []
for r in range(3):
    row = []
    for c in range (3):
        btn = Button(mainWindow, text = "", font=("Helvetica", 20), height=3, width=6, command=lambda row=r, col=c: btn_click(row, col))
        btn.grid(row=r, column=c, sticky="nsew")
        row.append(btn)
    buttonGrid.append(row)
```

```
def btn_click(row, col):
    global hasClicked, clickCount

    if buttonGrid[row][col]["text"] == "" and hasClicked == True:
        buttonGrid[row][col]["text"] = "X"
        computer_turn()
        clickCount += 1
```

```
def computer_turn():
    global clickCount
    empty_tiles = []
    
    for r in range(3):
        for c in range(3):
            if buttonGrid[r][c]["text"] == "":
                empty_tiles.append((r,c))
    if empty_tiles:
        row, col = random.choice(empty_tiles)
        buttonGrid[row][col]["text"] = "O"
        clickCount += 1
```

```
def who_wins(user):
    for i in range(3):
        if buttonGrid[i][0]["text"] == user and buttonGrid[i][1]["text"] == user and buttonGrid [i][2]["text"] == user:
            buttonGrid[i][0].config(bg="green")
            buttonGrid[i][1].config(bg="green")
            buttonGrid[i][2].config(bg="green")
            return True
        #check col win
        if buttonGrid[0][i]["text"] == user and buttonGrid[1][i]["text"] == user and buttonGrid [2][i]["text"] == user:
            buttonGrid[0][i].config(bg="green")
            buttonGrid[1][i].config(bg="green")
            buttonGrid[2][i].config(bg="green")
            return True
    #check diag win 0,0 to 2,2
    if buttonGrid[0][0]["text"] == user and buttonGrid[1][1]["text"] == user and buttonGrid [2][2]["text"] == user:
        buttonGrid[0][0].config(bg="green")
        buttonGrid[1][1].config(bg="green")
        buttonGrid[2][2].config(bg="green")
        return True
    #check diag win 0,2 to 2,0
    if buttonGrid[0][2]["text"] == user and buttonGrid[1][1]["text"] == user and buttonGrid [2][0]["text"] == user:
        buttonGrid[0][2].config(bg="green")
        buttonGrid[1][1].config(bg="green")
        buttonGrid[2][0].config(bg="green")
        return True
    return False
```

I've tried using a time.sleep() just to give a slight delay between moves but when i've used it, there's a delay on the players move as well. Ill give an image of what happens.
[issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Afghs.png)

Comment: Can't you add a win check after the user has done a move, and stop execution if they have?

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal ive added the win check im using in the question

Comment: "the computer makes its move at the exact same time" - Did you try putting the logic to check whether the player has won, *before* the logic to make the computer's move?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sleep would not help you because the problem is that you make the computer plays without checking first if the player has just won. A quick fix could be something like that:

```
def btn_click(row, col):
    global hasClicked, clickCount

    if buttonGrid[row][col]["text"] == "" and hasClicked == True:

        buttonGrid[row][col]["text"] = "X"
        clickCount += 1

        if who_wins('X') :  # Check if the player won
            your_victory_handling_function()
        else:  # Otherwise, the computer plays
            computer_turn()
            if who_wins('O') :  # The computer won
                your_defeat_handling_function()
```

Answer (score -3):

In your tic-tac-toe game, you can use time to provide a delay between the player's move and the computer's move.

The `btn_click()` method immediately follows the player's movement with `sleep()`. You could, for instance, add time.Before running the `computer_turn()` function, use the `sleep(0.5)` command to pause the execution for 0.5 seconds. Due to this latency, the player's move can be seen before the computer's move is executed. Change the length of sleep as necessary. positioning the time.A sequential gameplay experience is ensured for the player by using `sleep()` prior to the computer's move.